# How to change value inputted by user to corresponding dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am asking the user of the program to enter the number that corresponds to the measurement for it to be easier for them to right the answer. Is there a way to change their value to the value that corresponds to the list. Or if I made a new dictionary that had the number and name of the unit? I need to put the unit in word form eg "Teaspoon" into a list. Instead of using:

```
if unit == 2:
     unit = "Tablespoon"
```

and so on for every unit. Is there a more concise way to do this?

This is my code:

```
measurement=["Teaspoon","Tablespoon","Cup","Pinch","Grams"]
for i in range(len(measurement)):
    print(i+1, measurement[i])
unit = int(input("Enter number for the unit of the ingredient: "))
units = {1:"Teaspoon",2:"Tablespoon",3:"Cup",4:"Pinch",5:"Grams"}
```

I added this dicationary at the end because I thought this might be a good way of converting each number to the corresponding unit.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: You should have a look at the `enum` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: for example if the user entered "2" for the unit, which means "Tablespoon", how would I convert this input "2" to "Teaspoon", using the dictionary I provided in my code so I could append "Teaspoon" to my list instead of "2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `unit` as the key of the dictionary you have in order to retrieve the corresponding string:

```
units = {1:"Teaspoon",2:"Tablespoon",3:"Cup",4:"Pinch",5:"Grams"}
unit=2
unit=units[unit]
print(unit)
```

Result:

```
Tablespoon
```

You may want to look up [look up](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) the usage of dictionaries.

Remark:

Your could would become much prettier if you used [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/):

```
measurements=["Teaspoon","Tablespoon","Cup","Pinch","Grams"]
for i, measurement in enumerate(measurements):
    print(i, measurement)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realise it was this simple. I will mark your answer correct in a few minutes when it allows me :)  Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
measurement=["Teaspoon","Tablespoon","Cup","Pinch","Grams"]
for i in range(len(measurement)):
    print(i+1, measurement[i])
unit = int(input("Enter number for the unit of the ingredient: "))
units = {1:"Teaspoon",2:"Tablespoon",3:"Cup",4:"Pinch",5:"Grams"}
print(units[unit]) #this line should do it
```

It works as `dictionary[key]=value`